# Sonarqube : Can not see quality gate widget on dashboards

Tags: widget, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1.2

I'm using sonar 5.1.2.
I created a simple quality gate and associated it to my project.
Then I went on the main dashboard and added the Quality Gate widget, configured it for my project, and then saved.
Note, on the dashboard edition page (where you select widgets), under my new quality gate widget, it says : "No data".

When I return to the dashboard I cannot see the widget.  I can successfully add other widgets, but this one just won't show itself.

Note that my project is a maven multi-module project (a big one).  Tried it on a smaller project and had the same problem.

Is there something to know about this widget that could explain why I don't see it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to analyze the project after configuring Quality Gates.

Comment: Many widgets simply go invisible when they have nothing to show.